How to use defineModel with vee-validate?
I'm trying to build a Vue form using vee-validation with Composition API and zod.
The form validation is working correctly, but I want to use the new Vue 3.4 defineModel ref for the form input instead of the ref returned by vee-validate.
I have a working solution by adding a watch to each field, but on large forms that quickly becomes very verbose.
Is there a better way of linking my own defineModel ref to the vee-validate ref?
Here is a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-bbrhtj?file=components%2FMyForm.vue
<template>
  <form class="flex flex-col gap-6 m-6">
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
      <label for="businessName">Business Name</label>
      <InputText
        id="businessName"
        v-model="businessName"
        v-bind="businessNameAttrs"
      />
      <div class="text-xs text-red-500">
        {{ errors.businessName }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <Button @click="handleClick">Validate</Button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { z } from 'zod';

// I want to use this as the v-model
const businessName = defineModel<string>('businessName');

const formSchema = toTypedSchema(
  z.object({
    businessName: z
      .string({ required_error: 'Business Name is required' })
      .min(1, { message: 'Business Name is required' }),
  })
);

const { errors, defineField, validate } = useForm({
  validationSchema: formSchema,
});

// But vee-validate requires us to use this destructured ref for the input validation
const [businessNameVee, businessNameAttrs] = defineField('businessName');

// One possible workaround is creating a watch for each field but with lots of form fields it quickly becomes very verbose
watch(businessName, () => {
  businessNameVee.value = businessName.value;
});

const handleClick = () => {
  validate();
};
</script>


I don't use vee-validate a lot, but it looks that you need to use useField instead of useForm, it has sync option that does this. " large forms that quickly becomes very verbose" - I'm not sure it's a good idea to do this on large forms, you are expected to have a large amount of props this way. If you have a specific case in mind, consider asking about this.
